# How to Set Region when using Cloud Vision API Web Entities Detection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-search, google-cloud-vision

Is there a way of setting a region when using Cloud Vision API, more specifically when [detecting web entries and pages](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web)?

I consider it an important feature as Google search always considers the geo-location of a user when trying to display more relevant pages.

If not, what is the region used when triggering the API?

Thanks for all inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two specific questions here and let me attempt to answer that:

- `what is the region used when triggering the API?` : The specific API here is the Vision API. It is possible to restrict the API request/response processing to a specific region. By default, it is a global endpoint but specifically for Text based OCR, you can specify eu or us. Check this link: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#locations.
- Specifically for web entities, you cannot set the region while invoking the API. What you could do is to give the API a hint to use geo information in the images and then more relevant search results vis-a-vis the geotagging information available in the images can be returned. The specific element is `'includeGeoResults': true` in your request. Check this link: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web#using_geographic_metadata_with_a_local_image

Comment: Hi Romin, thanks a lot for your answer. The second point you mentioned is interesting. I assume it suggests that I should add some geolocation metadata to my images before I use them for searching (reversed image search). I was not able to find any example of how should this metadata looks like (what key, what value, what is the proposed metadata type, etc.). Do you, by any chance know where I can find such information?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, geo tag will include lat/lon information in the image itself. There are tools to add that or certain applications have the ability to add that.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. I will have a deeper look into that and add my findings later on